# Export module from TypeScript definition file

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to create a definition file for the Vogels library. This library wraps the AWS SDK, so it also includes a property that exports the entire AWS SDK.

```
declare module "vogels" {
  import AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  export function define(modelName: String, config: any): void;
  export var AWS: AWS;      /* THIS LINE DOESN'T TRANSPILE */
}
```

This library is used like this:

```
import vogels = require('vogels');

vogels.AWS.config.update({region: region});

var model = vogels.define('test', {
  ..
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, exporting the AWS property from the "vogels" module doesn't work, because AWS is not considered a type. How can I export the AWS property without replicating the entire AWS definitions in my module?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the way to export the entire AWS module and the `define` function:

```
declare module "vogels" {
  import AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  function define(modelName: String, config: any): void;

  export = { AWS, define }
}
```

You can only have a single `export =` in a module, so all exported variables should be in that line (of course you can split it across multiple lines). Don't export anything else, but only define interfaces, variables, ... The actual export is done later.